# How to move a specific entry to the header of the queue in c?

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

As we know queue is `FIFO`,does it support such kind of operation?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the FIFO queue.  Since there is no standard implementation (as in, the C standard does not define one), there is no way anyone can answer your question without a lot more information.

Comment: You have asked 96 questions; you have accepted answers to 48 of those.  You have not contributed a single answer; you have never upvoted anything.  SO is meant to be a two-way street; you should demonstrate that you've learned from SO by providing answers to questions, and recognize your peers by upvoting answers and questions that are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you want to be be able to put objects at specific positions, a queue is not the right data structure.

A deque lets you insert new items at either the back or the front. Once inserted, however, you can't normally rearrange them.

A priority queue maintains some specified ordering among the items, so the "next" is always the highest priority (based on some criteria you need to establish).

If you want to rearrange items after insertion, then you're normally looking at something that isn't very queue-like at all (much more like a normal array).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're looking for a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

Comment: Abstract question, abstract answer :-D